# how to add a rule to a field where name is an array in jquery validation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

hi i am using jquery validation plugin . i can set rules to my fields by there name

example

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
```

and set rules

```
        rules: {
            name: {
                required:true,
                        minlength: 3,
                        maxlength: 250   
            }
             }
```

but i have a checkbox group like this

```
<input id="cooking-facilities" type="checkbox" name="additional[]" value="cooking-facilities" tabindex="123456789">
```

the name is `additional[]` here .

but when i try to use like

```
        rules: {
            additional[]: {
                required:true 
            }
         }
```

it gives errors . how can i set rules in jquery validation plugin to my check-box group

i am using

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

please help....................................

Comment: Be more specific on the "it gives errors" line.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and rename `name="additional[]"` - dropping the square brackets!

Comment: @ Barry . i have about 15 check boxes , they have the same name additional[] . because i want to get the values of them in server , i don't want to set individually

Comment: @Baszz  it gives error ----------->   missing : after property id
 addtional[]: {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not read the docs?

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Reference#Fields_with_complex_names_.28brackets.2C_dots.29